# Javascript - Why isn't my while loop executing? (Pong)

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, pong

Amateur here :) Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but why isn't my while loop executing? It should draw a pink rectangle with two black rectangle for paddles. P.S. Yes, I know that i<10 doesn't make sense, but it is a placeholder for later and shouldn't impact the running of the code. Anyways, here's my code-

```
    //set up the javascript canvas
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var i = 1;

//Game loop
while (i < 10) {
  //register pressed keys
  //var x = event.key;

  if (window.event) {
    var keynum = event.keyCode;
  } else if (event.which) {
    var keynum = event.which;
  }

  //draw the pink background
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 315, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFC0CB";

  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Draw the player's paddle
  ctx.beginPath();
  var playerY = 35;
  ctx.rect(15, playerY, 10, 25);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Draw the bot's paddle
  ctx.beginPath();
  var botY = 35;
  ctx.rect(280, botY, 10, 25);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Are any errors logged to the console?

Comment: No events can occur while the loop is executing. JavaScript is single-threaded and non-preemptable. You should use event listeners to wait for key presses.

Comment: Also, `window.event` is not a standard variable. It doesn't exist in Firefox. The event is passed as a parameter to the event listener function.

Comment: Your loop is executing. It's just breaking during its first iteration. Check your console. Although, like @Barmar says. You should look into event listeners for this type of task. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thanks, @Snarf you helped fix it!